# Fastest rising factorial (Pochhammer function) in python

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sympy

I need to compute the [rising factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_factorial) of big numbers, the best I found until now is the rising factorial function from the sympy package [sympy package](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/gamma.html?highlight=rf#mpmath.rf), that is really nice, but I would still need something faster.

What I would need exactly is a really fast version of this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from numpy import prod

def my_rising_factorial(degree, elt):
    return sum([prod(i) for i in combinations(xrange(1,degree),elt)])
```

EDIT:
that is given a rising factorial, x(n) = x (x + 1)(x + 2)...(x + n-1), I would like to retrieve a given multiplier of its expanded formula.

eg:

given: x(6) = x(x + 1)(x + 2)(x + 3)(x + 5)(x + 6)

and the expanded form: x(6) = x**6 + 15*x**5 + 85*x**4 + 225*x**3 + 274*x**2 + 120*x

I want some how to get one of those multipliers (in this case 1, 15, 85, 225, 274, 120)

with "my_rising_factorial()" it works well... but really slowly

```
>>>[my_rising_factorial(6,i) for i in xrange (6)]
[1.0, 15, 85, 225, 274, 120]
```

Comment: I don't understand your example function, it doesn't seem to match up with the definition of the rising factorial x_n = x*(x+1)*...*(x+n-1) to me.

Comment: @zephyr yes, this is true, and it is my fault I did not explain it well, what I want are not exactly the final value of the rising factorial function for a given x. But the multipliers of the expanded rising formula. I edit the post in order to explain this better. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this package: http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/nzmath/

Like job said, the function you want is Stirling Number of the 1st kind (I'd worked out the recursive definition and was about to post it, but I didn't know the name).

The function is nzmath.combinatorial.stirling1

Answer (score 3):

The other versions I know about are in [mpmath.qfunctions](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/qfunctions.html#qp) and [scipy.special.orthogonal](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.special.orthogonal.html#poch).

If neither of those nor SymPy are fast enough, you can try PyPy (another implementation of Python) to speed them up. If that doesn't work, try Psyco (an extension module), Shedskin or Nuitka (Python compilers), Cython, or writing it in C.

Answer (score 2):

These are just the unsigned [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). I don't have a fast method of computing them, but you could probably use the fact that they follow a simple recursive relationship: `S(n,k) = (n-1)*S(n-1,k) + S(n-1,k-1)`

Comment: I finally understood and tried this relationship in my code, in my case using it is not as efficient as computing the stirlings that I need... but surely in most cases it is the best solution. thanks.